# relative path doesn't work after adding a rewrite rule for appending trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have an index page placed in `/forum/section1/.` I have a rule to automatically redirect to the index page when I browse `exampledomain.com/forum/section1/`. Sometimes when I forgot the trailing slash, it keeps loading and never goes to the index page. I have added a rule to append a trailing slash to every request:

```
RewriteEngine on
#From http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/trailing-slash/ 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
# Don't apply to images/css/js/ajax files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|jpe?g|ico|css|js|gif|png|php)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://exampledomain.com/$1/ [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|jpe?g|ico|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]

#Remove php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

The rules are working, but all of the relative paths become invalid. For example, I have a form on the index page:

```
       `<form action='index' method='POST'></form>`
```

Instead of accessing `exampledomain/forum/section1/index/`, it would redirect to `exampledomain/forum/section1/index/index`. I know changing relative paths to absolute paths would fix the problem, but is there a way to fix that with the rewrite rules?

Comment: where is your .htaccess located?

Comment: you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/forum/" />` but your links should be: `<form action='section1/index' method='POST'></form>`

Comment: @PanamaJack I put all the rules in the apache config file.