# How to redirect to 404 when url is pointing to an existing folder (no trailing slash). HAproxy or mod-rewrite related

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, haproxy

I am using HAProxy listening on 80 to send requests to a node server (port:3000) or php server (4000); I also have CSF installed which have ports 3000 and 80 available.

It works okay when I browse a page at `http://example.com/forum/1/page.php`, but sometimes when I accidentally enter `example.com/forum/1` (no trailing slash), it keeps loading and eventually leads to an error page `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. The address bar shows that it has redirected to `http://example.com:4000/forum/1/`.

Since I don't have the 4000 port open, when I keep going to `example.com/forum/1` a multiple times, it would trigger a block by CSF. My question is, can I redirect all the requests that are pointing to an actual folder `example.com/forum/1` (no trailing slash) to an 404 page? I have tried adding a rewrite rule to append a trailing slash to every request, but that would break all of my relative paths (see my issue at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586842/relative-path-doesnt-work-after-adding-a-rewrite-rule-for-appending-trailing-sl)).

So what I want to know is, why was I redirected to `http://example.com:4000/forum/1/` from `http://example.com/forum/1`? Was it caused by HAproxy?

Some HAproxy config:

```
frontend all 0.0.0.0:80
    timeout client 1h
    # use apache2 as default webserver for incoming traffic
    default_backend apache2

backend apache2
    balance roundrobin

    option forwardfor
    server apache2 myIpAddress:4000 weight 1 maxconn 1024 check 

    # server must be contacted within 5 seconds
    timeout connect 5s
    # all headers must arrive within 3 seconds
    timeout http-request 3s
    # server must respond within 25 seconds. should equal client timeout
    timeout server 25s
```

Here's my rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpg|css|js|gif|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `/forum/1` is a valid physical directory you get redirected to `/forum/1/` due to this setting:

```
DirectorySlash On
```

which is used by a module called `mod_dir` that adds a trailing slash after directories if it is missing.

You can of course turn this flag off by using:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

but [be aware of security implications](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash).

To be more secure you also need:

```
Options -Indexes
```

to turn off directory listing.

**Security Warning** (copied from linked manual)

Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where `mod_autoindex` is active (`Options +Indexes`) and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, index.html) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the `index.html` file. But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.

---

**Update:** To answer this part of the question:

> **My question is, can I redirect all the requests that are pointing to an actual folder `example.com/forum/1` (no trailing slash) to an 404 page?**

You can use this code in `/forum/1/.htaccess`:

```
DirectorySlash On
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ - [L,R=404]
```

This will force a trailing slash so that rewrite rule can used to send 404 error.

Answer (score 2):

In your .htaccess file add the following code. Replace /404.php with any file you want.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this at the top of your .htaccess

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteOptions AllowNoSlash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ - [L,R=404]
```

DirectorySlash Off will make directories accessible with no-slash without redirect.

But the problem is non-slash version will simply list the directory contents.
I order to avoid this, **RewriteOptions AllownoSlash** is added.

Now when the folder is requested without a slash, 404 error is raised.